# Haskell - Rose Trees Paths

Tags: haskell, path, tree, binary, project

I'm doing a small project in Haskell, and I'm having difficulty in creating a function Paths of a "Rose Tree". My Rose Tree has a different point where I can have four possibilities since the beginning.

What I was trying to do was:

```
data RoseTree a = Start [RoseTree Movimento] | Node a [RoseTree Movimento]
        deriving (Eq, Show)

paths :: RoseTree Movimento -> [[Movimento]]
paths (Start []) = []
paths (Node n []) = [[n]]
paths (Node n ns) = map ((:) n . concat . paths) ns
paths (Start xs) = undefined
```

PS -> Tree Example :

```
data Movimento = AndarEsquerda | AndarDireita | Trepar | InterageCaixa 
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

Start [Node AndarEsquerda [Node AndarDireita [Node AndarEsquerda [],Node Trepar []]],Node Trepar [Node AndarDireita [Node AndarDireita []],Node AndarEsquerda [Node AndarEsquerda []]]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[AndarEsquerda, AndarDireita, AndarEsquerda],
 [AndarEsquerda, AndarDireita, Trepar],
 [Trepar, AndarDireita, AndarDireita],
 [Trepar, AndarEsquerda, AndarEsquerda]]
```

[Tree Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpuTS.png)

Comment: How did you define the rose tree?

Comment: Sorry I really forgot it: data RoseTree a = Start [RoseTree Movimento] | Node a [RoseTree Movimento]
                                               deriving (Eq, Show)

Comment: You gave us and example of some input data, why not also give an example of what you expect `paths example`  to give.

Comment: Input : Start [Node AndarEsquerda [Node AndarDireita [Node AndarEsquerda [],Node Trepar []]],Node Trepar [Node AndarDireita [Node AndarDireita []],Node AndarEsquerda [Node AndarEsquerda []]]]                                                                                               Output :[[AndarEsquerda, AndarDireita, Andar Esquerda], [AndarEsquerda, AndarDireita, Trepar], [Trepar, AndarDireita, AndarDireita], [Trepar, AndarEsquerda, AndarEsquerda]]

Comment: Afonso, you edit the question. I was what `paths input` should result. And btw, to solve the missing branch you need to ask yourself how is Start different from Node.

Comment: @DavidLukas This is a bad translation. It means to climb. Try "trepar o muro". Its swear word connotation depends on the context. The only bad taste here is mixing languages. Either program in English or program in Portuguese, not both.

Answer (score 1):

In your code is an undefined right-hand side of expression `paths (Start xs)`.
It does not return the desired output if I defined using the expression `(paths n) ++ (paths (Start ns))`.

Trivial cases [] are OK, but you do not **go through the list with `(n:ns)` recursion** to make the trivial ones occur. You iterate using the map function, which is an alternative to recursion.

I use the `map` function for scrolling to the width and recursion for browsing to the depth of the tree.

```
paths2 :: RoseTree Movimento -> [[Movimento]]
paths2 (Start []) = []
paths2 (Node m []) = [[m]]
paths2 (Node m (n:ns)) = map ((++) [m]) ((paths2 n) ++ (paths2 (Start ns)))
paths2 (Start (n:ns)) = (paths2 n) ++ (paths2 (Start ns))
```

Output:

```
[[AndarEsquerda,AndarDireita,AndarEsquerda],
[AndarEsquerda,AndarDireita,Trepar],
[Trepar,AndarDireita,AndarDireita],
[Trepar,AndarEsquerda,AndarEsquerda]]
```

---

Edit: You may like using the `(n:ns)` from the `Start`.

```
paths2 :: RoseTree Movimento -> [[Movimento]]
paths2 (Start []) = []
paths2 (Node m []) = [[m]]
paths2 (Node m ns) = map ((:) m) $ paths2 (Start ns)
paths2 (Start (n:ns)) = paths2 n ++ paths2 (Start ns)
```